# Rounded UIButton with dark effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, rounded-corners

I need to create gradient buttons with rounded corners and black shadow inside as in screenshot. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: i couldnt make it even closer. what i got is glossy buttons using an extension.

Comment: Have a suggestion.why can’t you use an image? this makes your work lot easier..create an image with  black shadow inside and use it as button image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's not a black shadow. The shadow is more like a bright version of the button's base color. The button itself has a dark (black) border.

To achieve this, you might do the following.

1. Download this project: https://github.com/inamiy/YIInnerShadowView
2. The important class is `YIInnerShadowLayer`. Add that to your project.
3. To reproduce the exact effect, you should change the color of the shadow. Do this in the `init` method of `YIInnerShadowLayer`. Even better, provide a new init method that takes a UIColor as its argument and assigns that to the `shadowColor` property. A very generic approach would be to set the shadowColor to white.
4. Add an instance of that class to your view (button, label, whatever, but let's call it `myView` for now). To see how to add that layer, you can look in the `_init` method of `YIInnerShadowView`.
5. Set the frame of the new layer to the bounds of `myView`.
6. For the rounded corners do `myView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;`
7. For the black border do `myView.layer.borderWidth = 2; myView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;`

Feel free to ask if something is unclear.

My end result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have actually written a category for that after thinking i will not find an answer. Created two layers one is gradient and over the gradient a black shadow. It worked too. Will add it to github soon.

Answer (score 1):

for rounded rectangles
Go to Identity Inspector -> user defined runtime attributes

For corner radius
1. click on '+' button
2. Give value of key path = layer.cornerRadius, Type=Number & value = 2

For border width repeat same steps but key path = layer.borderWidth

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = YOUBUTTON.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (__bridge id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
YOUBUTTON.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Then just change the colours to the ones you want .. ?

Comment: this makes the button gradient. it looks close but not what i needed.

Comment: OK. Well play with the gradient a bit to get what you need ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can set corner radius of your UIButton round.

```
self.yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10; // this value vary as per your desire
self.yourButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want **UIButton roundrect** then used one:

You have to add an import in any file you want to use **CALayers** below framewrok.

**`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`**

```
  // assuming you have a UIButton is YourButton

YourButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2;//give yourbutton.size.width/2 it's look better
YourButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
YourButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
```

May it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add Quartzcore framework in your project

and import **#import < QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h >** in your View controller

```
UIButton *btngrident=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btngrident setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 150, 45)];
[self.view addSubview:btngrident];

 CALayer *layer = btngrident.layer;
 layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
 layer.masksToBounds = YES;
 layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
 layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5f alpha:0.2f].CGColor;

 // Add Shine<Br/>

 CAGradientLayer *shineLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
 shineLayer.frame = layer.bounds;>

 shineLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.4f].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.2f].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.75f alpha:0.2f].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4f alpha:0.2f].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.4f].CGColor,
                         nil];

 shineLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                            nil];
 [layer addSublayer:shineLayer];
```

Comment: that makes a glossy button too.